# Necessary and sufficient conditions for the sum of two numbers to divide their product

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to find necessary and sufficient conditions for the sum of two numbers to divide their product.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By numbers, do you mean natural numbers?

Comment: @Avatar .integer number $\Bbb Z$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a solution of this problem [in this post on codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2327/find-the-no-of-pairs-whose-sum-divides-the-product-from-0-1000000000). Let me review it, hopefully correctly.

Assume $a, b$ not both zero. Let $d = \gcd(a,b) \ne 0$. Then $a = a' d, b = b' d$, and we have that $a + b = (a' + b') d$ divides $ab = a'b'd^2$, so $a' + b'$ divides $a'b'd$.

Since $a'$ and $b'$ are coprime, if $p$ is a prime divisor of $a'+ b'$, this must divide $d$. This is because $p$ divides $a'b'd$, so it must divide one of the factors. If $p$ divides $a'$, say, then since $p$ divides $a' + b'$, and then $b'$, against the assumption that $a', b'$ are coprime. Thus $a'+b'$ divides $d$.

So the recipe appears to be the following. Choose any coprime pair $a', b'$, and construct $$a = c (a'+b') a', \qquad b = c (a'+b') b',$$
for arbitrary $c$.

Comment: Nice! Yours is much better.

Comment: why you let $d=a'+b'$?

Comment: @agustin, you're right, bad notation, just fixed, thanks.

Comment: This seems to be arguing that "every prime p dividing a'+b' divides d" implies "a'+b' divides d". That doesn't hold, but I believe it can be fixed simply by strengthening the antecedent to "every prime power p^k dividing a'+b' divides d".  So I made a suggested edit to change "if p is a prime divisor of" to "if p^k is a prime power dividing".  The edit was rejected (harshly), so I'm framing it as a comment instead.

Answer (score 3):

If, $\dfrac{ab}{a+b}=n$

Then,

$\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}=\dfrac{1}{n}$

I don't know if this is to be considered an answer or not.

Comment: looks necessary and sufficient so looks like an answer to me

Comment: But it's not particularly elegant, is it?

Comment: It's not a matter of elegance, it is just that it does not give a constructive recipe to find all such $a, b$. I have given one in my answer, quoting a post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Dividing $\rm\:(A\!+\!B)n = AB\:$ by $\rm\:d=(A,B)\:$ yields $\rm\: (\color{#C00}{a\!+\!b})n = d\color{#C00}{ab},\:$ for $\rm\,a,b = A/d,B/d$.

$\rm(a\!+\!b,b)\!=\!(a,b)\!=\!1\!=\!(a\!+\!b,a)\:$ so by Euclid $\rm\:(\color{#C00}{a\!+\!b,ab})\!=\!1\:$ so $\rm\:a\!+\!b\mid d,\,$ so $\rm\,(a\!+\!b)c = d.$

So $\rm\, A,B = da,db = (a\!+\!b)ca,(a\!+\!b)cb,\,$ and $\rm\:A\!+\!B = (a\!+\!b)^2c\mid (a\!+\!b)^2 c^2 ab = AB.$

Comment: Above, vector equations $\rm\ [x,y] = [u,v]\ $ mean $\rm\ x=u,\ y=v,\ $ and $\rm\ c[u,v] = [cu,cv].\ \ $

Comment: You had me fooled that you were Bill Dubuque with this formatting.

Answer (score 0):

A simple condition can be found that does not require using the GCD and yet allows you to determine all the solutions. But let me rephrase the problem:

Given any integer $x$, find all integers $y$ such that $x+y \mid xy$.

We know that $x+y \mid x(x+y)$ and so

$x+y \mid x(x+y) - xy = x^2$. The RHS does not depend on $y$ anymore.

Therefore, $y=d-x$ for all $d \mid x^2$