# Find tuples $(a,b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

(Second time I ask this because the previous was not very clear so I deleted it)
Hi, I've trying to solve this problem (competitive programming) called Divide a days ago, it's states:

Given $p,q,n \le 10^{10}$, find all the tuples such that:

$\frac {ab} {a+b} = c $

($a+b|ab$, $a \in [1;p]$, $b\in [1;q]$, $c\in [1;n]$, all integers)

Note: this is not about to check whether $ab$ is divisible by $a+b$ but to find how many valid tuples (a,b) when put into that expression above, results results in a number $c\le n$

As the values $p,q,n$ are too big and cannot be calculated by brute-force, is there a way to calculate how much of such tuples exists in $O(1)$?

Original problem: https://dmoj.uclv.edu.cu/problem/2023orcop1112b

What I've reached by myself:

1. When $a=b$ then $\frac a 2 \le n$ and $a \le 2n$ , so that gives some tuples of the form $(2k, 2k)$
2. When $a=kb$ then $\frac {kb} {k+1}$ as $k$ and $k+1$ are coprime, must find a $k+1$ that divides $b$, (can be easily calculated)

Nothing more useful :/

Comment: 1. Can you credit the source where you encountered this problem?  2. What approaches have you already considered?  What is the best algorithm you have found so far?  3. Is $c$ given as part of the input?

Comment: Please don't duplicate your [prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4766429/242). The characterization of solutions in the linked dupes there (and now here) easily leads to algorithms to enumerate solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search yielded some good explanations of this problem:

[Necessary and sufficient conditions for the sum of two numbers to divide their product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324518/necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-the-sum-of-two-numbers-to-divide-their-p)

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2327/find-the-no-of-pairs-whose-sum-divides-the-product-from-0-1000000000

In general, I think that with problems like this, it is often a good idea to split up terms into common factors and relatively prime integers (i.e., $a = a'g, b = b'g,$ for $a', b'$ relatively prime).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242). These (and other) links were already given in the prior version of the question.

Comment: Okay thanks emilg ! I'll try it